# bash не переходит по ssh

Tags: bash

bash скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

expect -c "spawn ssh tropin@77.222.62.31; expect \"Password:\"; send \"pass\r\";"
cd public_html
```

на удалённый переходит, но далее команду cd public_html запускает на лольной машине, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы скрипт перейдя на хост работал уже там, даже запустить bash скрипт на хосте не могу с помощью запущенного с локали bash.

Comment: рекомендую paramiko

Comment: @eri спасибо! Будем пробовать

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh user@host "command 1; command 2; etc"
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант, но не совсем то, что нужно.

Comment: Тогда я видимо не так вопрос понял:) Что конктретно не подходит ? @АлегКонин

Comment: На удаленном сервере нужно будет запускать команды с вводом паролей, те. нужно будет ожидать запрос и отправлять пароль с помощью скрипта.

Comment: Что то с ходу не скажу как такое релиазовать)